# What is the correct setup for the auto-login of a returning, authenticated user with the Javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, autologin

Hey fellow Facebook developers,

I've read dozens of related questions and hopefully tried every related example on developers.facebook.com but I can't get this one to work:

1. A user has visited my website and authorized the permissions I request from him via

   ```
   FB.login(callback, {
       scope: 'publish_actions,user_actions:news,user_interests'
   });
   ```

   after calling

   ```
   FB.init({
       appId: 'xxx', // App ID
       status: true, // check login status
       cookie: true,
       xfbml: true // parse XFBML
   });
   ```
2. I can now successfully request an access token that is valid for some time and use that to query all kind of information about the user.
3. Without logging out anywhere (Facebook or my own website), if I now navigate to that page again (or just hit reload), I would expect to immediately be able to use

   ```
   FB.getLoginStatus(callback)
   ```

   and receive a response of `connected`. In my understanding, the user should not have to click anything anymore.

What I do get, though, is `unknown`. No matter in what browser and no matter whether I am using a real developer profile or a Facebook test user.

I also have subscribed to the events `auth.authResponseChange` and `auth.statusChange` but they only fire, if I explicitly call `FB.login()`.

It says in the [example in the Facebook SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/#jssdk) that my `FB.init()` from above should already get the necessary information from Facebook on page load time and that the events should fire accordingly.

Since I tried [so many examples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) already and really think I understand the documentation, I can't see where the error happens.

**Is there anything I'm missing, anything I am misunderstanding or a timing problem I should be aware of?**

On a side note, I have already tried more than the mentioned Facebook events, a forced status update through `FB.getLoginStatus(callback, true)`, running the code step by step by entering it in the Javascript console of Chrome and more suggestions from SO and Facebook forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `status: true`, the `FB.getLoginStatus` response object will be cached by the SDK and subsequent calls to `FB.getLoginStatus` will return data from this cached response.

To get around this, you have to call `FB.getLoginStatus` with the second parameter set to true to force a roundtrip to Facebook - effectively refreshing the cache of the response object.

Example:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : '',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml  : true,
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
        //console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            alert(accessToken);
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //login function
        } else {
            //login function
        }
    }, true);

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        //console.log('The status of the session changed to: '+response.status);
        alert(response.status);
    });
};
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Philip, but I'm afraid that is precisely my problem. I *always* get `response.status` as `unknown`, no matter if I use the cached or uncached value.

Comment: If I paste your example into a page that only loads the Javascript SDK and fill in my already authorized app id, I end up in the last `else` clause. Maybe my app is configured the wrong way. Does this exact example work for you?

Comment: Yes it work fine. Try to set the status to false and see what you get in your getLoginStatus() function!

Comment: That's crazy. I tried that before, and basically any other kind of switch I can imagine. Sorry to ask again, but I just want to make sure I understand: Are you telling me that just visiting the site again after giving it the permissions automatically provides you with a `response.status` of `connected`, without clicking anything?

Comment: Yes, thats correct! After you approve the app, you will be redirected in the redirect_uri of your function. There you must have a response.status connected.

Comment: Philip, thanks for your help. I had to realize that my cookie blocker prevented me from logging in automatically after refreshing the page. You're example as well as my original code worked fine, just the cookies were prevented from being set. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

As an additional information to Philip's accepted answer, I would like to mention that a **cookie blocker** was the actual reason the auto-login did not work.

Make sure to disable any plugins you have running before testing your code and assuming "real world" conditions.

Comment: Specifically: the browser must be set to **allow third-pary cookies**